# How do you define hashbang (#!) fragment routing with react-router-dom v6.9?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, hashbang

I'm migrating from react-router-dom v5 to v6.9.  In the older library you could define hashbang (#!) routes by simply putting it in the basename.  Now it looks like we're to use HashRouter, or another option is to add the useHash prop on the BrowserRouter.  The problem I'm running into is that the hashtype is assumed to be simply hash (#) and there's no way to define hashbang (#!).  Is there any way to define routing with hashbang instead of plain hash?

These use to work in react-router-dom v5:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/webresources/test_/search#!">
  <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
  <Route path="/configuration" element={<ConfigPage />} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

or

```
<HashRouter basename="/webresources/test_/search" hashtype="hashbang">
  <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
  <Route path="/configuration" element={<ConfigPage />} />
</HashRouter>
```

How do you route hashbang routes with react-router-dom v6.9?

Comment: I don't believe there is anything other than the plain old hash in the `HashRouter`.

Comment: `#!` was a really bad idea that we thankfully only had to live with briefly, because it basically violates how URL parsing is supposed to work. Don't use it, use normal URL patterns, with normal browser history updates.

Comment: The problem is that we have Dynamics CRM hosting an iframe and we serve this React project in it.  When we were on v5 and using #! the project renders fine.  But when we switched to v6.9 and used only # without the !, Dynamics CRM would not render the page in the iframe.  I'm not sure why tho, because in my own tests with plain iframes it doesn't matter.  We're kind of guessing the ! matters to the CRM code for some reason as just bringing the project up outside of an iframe it works fine also.  I have very little access to the CRM extension that hosts the iframe however, so I'm sort of stuck.